# Watir 'Wait' doesn't wait

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, watir

gem "watir", "6.9"

Trying to execute this code

`2.times { next_button.when_present.click }`
or like this
`2.times { next_button.wait_until(&:present?).click }`

And getting this error

> ```
>  Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException:
>    unable to locate element: #<Watir::Button: located: false; {:class=>"course-player__content-next-btn", :tag_name=>"button"}>
> ```

But I'm telling Watir to wait for an element before clicking on that!

What's going on? I'm not a fan of sleeps and don't want to resort to using them!

Thank you!

P.S. next_button has been found and identified.
The code works with sleeps and doesn't wait for an element by default.

Comment: This does not provide a solution to the question, please ask your own Question if you are having trouble or use comments to add support to OP's question

Comment: As of Watir 6, you don't need to tell it to wait, it happens automatically. Based on the error, it appears that you haven't defined `next_button` to match the element correctly. What is the HTML?

Comment: I've identified ```next_button```.
So it works like this 

```
        sleep 1
        next_button.click
        sleep 1
        next_button.click
```

But not like this
```2.times { next_button.when_present.click }```
And so waiting in Watir doesn't happen automatically for me, for some reason!

Comment: I'm guessing there is a race condition where it clicks it twice before the first click is registered. Try this: `2.times { next_button.click; next_button.wait_until(&:stale?) }`

Comment: I'm getting this error
```Can not check staleness of unused element```

Comment: @titusfortner

Do you have an idea?

Comment: @Anna, the suggestion by @titusfortner should be `2.times { btn = next_button; btn.click; btn.wait_until(&:stale?) }`

Comment: @Anna, if the above comment doesn't solve the problem, you might want to share how `next_button` is defined. Is it pure Watir or something defined by say the Page-Object gem?

Answer (score 2):

You can try for example - 
if element is visible in gui and exist in html = continue to click

```
 browser.element(class: button_ok).wait_until_present
 browser.element(class: button_ok).click
```

or  - if element is exist in html and it is visible in gui = continue to click

```
 browser.element(class: button_ok).present?
 browser.element(class: button_ok).click
```

or   -  if element is exist in html = continue to click

```
browser.element(class: button_ok).exists?
browser.element(class: button_ok).click
```

or - wait until element is not visible(disapear)

```
browser.element(class: button_ok).wait_while_present
browser.element(class: button_ok).click
```

Hope it will help you.

of course button_ok is variable 
button_ok = "path"

Answer (score 0):

As of 6.15 `#wait_while_present` and `#wait_until_present` are deprecated. For versions 6.2 through 6.14 these methods had subtly different behaviour or from `.wait_until(&:present?)` & `.wait_while(&:present?)`. This is no longer the case and these methods should no longer be used.